# Как зафиксировать камеру на персонаже в pygame&

Tags: python, pygame

Реализовал функцию камеры для персонажа в игре, но не получается закрепить камеру, код представлен ниже , можете подсказать?
Здесь предствлен код игры

import pygame
from player import Player
from enemies import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

```
# Define some colors

    BLACK = (0,0,0)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    BLUE = (0,0,255)
    RED = (255,0,0)
    class Camera(object):
        def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
            self.camera_func = camera_func
            self.state = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        def apply(self, target):
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        def update(self, target):
            self.state =self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
    def camera_func(camera, taget_rect):
        l = -taget_rect.x + SCREEN_WIDTH/2
        t = -taget_rect.y + SCREEN_HEIGHT/2
        w,h = camera.width, camera.height
    
        l = min(0, l)
        l = max (-(camera.width-SCREEN_WIDTH), l)
        t = max(-(camera.height-SCREEN_HEIGHT), t)
        t = min(0, t)
        return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)
    
    
    class Game(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,40)
            self.about = False
            self.game_over = True
            # Create the variable for the score
            self.score = 0
            # Create the font for displaying the score on the screen
            self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,35)
            # Create the menu of the game
            self.menu = Menu(("Start","About","Exit"),font_color = WHITE,font_size=60)
            # Create the player
            self.player = Player(32,128,"1_peredel.png")
            # Create the blocks that will set the paths where the player can go
            self.horizontal_blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
            self.vertical_blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
            # Create a group for the dots on the screen
            self.dots_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
            # Set the enviroment:
            for i,row in enumerate(enviroment()):
                for j,item in enumerate(row):
                    if item == 1:
                        self.horizontal_blocks.add(Block(j*32+8,i*32+8,BLACK,16,16))
                    elif item == 2:
                        self.vertical_blocks.add(Block(j*32+8,i*32+8,BLACK,16,16))
            # Create the enemies
            self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
            self.enemies.add(Slime(288,96,0,2))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(288,320,0,-2))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(544,128,0,2))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(32,224,0,2))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(160,64,2,0))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(448,64,-2,0))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(640,448,2,0))
            self.enemies.add(Slime(448,320,2,0))
            # Add the dots inside the game
            for i, row in enumerate(enviroment()):
                for j, item in enumerate(row):
                    if item != 0:
                        self.dots_group.add(Ellipse(j*32+12,i*32+12,WHITE,8,8))
    
            # Load the sound effects
            self.pacman_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_sound.ogg")
            self.game_over_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("game_over_sound.ogg")
    
    
        def process_events(self):
            for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
                    return True
                self.menu.event_handler(event)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        if self.game_over and not self.about:
                            if self.menu.state == 0:
                                # ---- START ------
                                self.__init__()
                                self.game_over = False
                            elif self.menu.state == 1:
                                # --- ABOUT ------
                                self.about = True
                            elif self.menu.state == 2:
                                # --- EXIT -------
                                # User clicked exit
                                return True
    
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.player.move_right()
    
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.player.move_left()
    
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.player.move_up()
    
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.player.move_down()
                    
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        self.game_over = True
                        self.about = False
    
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.player.stop_move_right()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.player.stop_move_left()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.player.stop_move_up()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.player.stop_move_down()
    
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.player.explosion = True
                        
            return False
    
        def run_logic(self):
            if not self.game_over:
                self.player.update(self.horizontal_blocks,self.vertical_blocks)
                block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.dots_group,True)
                # When the block_hit_list contains one sprite that means that player hit a dot
                if len(block_hit_list) > 0:
                    # Here will be the sound effect
                    self.pacman_sound.play()
                    self.score += 1
                block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.enemies,True)
                if len(block_hit_list) > 0:
                    self.player.explosion = True
                    self.game_over_sound.play()
                self.game_over = self.player.game_over
                self.enemies.update(self.horizontal_blocks,self.vertical_blocks)
               # tkMessageBox.showinfo("GAME OVER!","Final Score = "+(str)(GAME.score))    
    
        def display_frame(self,screen):
            # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            # --- Drawing code should go here
            if self.game_over:
                if self.about:
                    self.display_message(screen,"It is an arcade Game")
                    #"a maze containing various dots,\n"
                    #known as Pac-Dots, and four ghosts.\n"
                    #"The four ghosts roam the maze, trying to kill Pac-Man.\n"
                    #"If any of the ghosts hit Pac-Man, he loses a life;\n"
                    #"the game is over.\n")
                else:
                    self.menu.display_frame(screen)
            else:
                # --- Draw the game here ---
                self.horizontal_blocks.draw(screen)
                self.vertical_blocks.draw(screen)
                draw_enviroment(screen)
                self.dots_group.draw(screen)
                self.enemies.draw(screen)
                screen.blit(self.player.image,self.player.rect)
                #text=self.font.render("Score: "+(str)(self.score), 1,self.RED)
                #screen.blit(text, (30, 650))
                # Render the text for the score
                text = self.font.render("Score: " + str(self.score),True,GREEN)
                # Put the text on the screen
                screen.blit(text,[120,20])
                
            # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
            pygame.display.flip()
    
        def display_message(self,screen,message,color=(255,0,0)):
            label = self.font.render(message,True,color)
            # Get the width and height of the label
            width = label.get_width()
            height = label.get_height()
            # Determine the position of the label
            posX = (SCREEN_WIDTH /2) - (width /2)
            posY = (SCREEN_HEIGHT /2) - (height /2)
            # Draw the label onto the screen
            screen.blit(label,(posX,posY))
    
    
    class Menu(object):
        state = 0
        def __init__(self,items,font_color=(0,0,0),select_color=(255,0,0),ttf_font=None,font_size=25):
            self.font_color = font_color
            self.select_color = select_color
            self.items = items
            self.font = pygame.font.Font(ttf_font,font_size)
            
        def display_frame(self,screen):
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
                if self.state == index:
                    label = self.font.render(item,True,self.select_color)
                else:
                    label = self.font.render(item,True,self.font_color)
                
                width = label.get_width()
                height = label.get_height()
                
                posX = (SCREEN_WIDTH /2) - (width /2)
                # t_h: total height of text block
                t_h = len(self.items) * height
                posY = (SCREEN_HEIGHT /2) - (t_h /2) + (index * height)
                
                screen.blit(label,(posX,posY))
            
        def event_handler(self,event):
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if self.state > 0:
                        self.state -= 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if self.state < len(self.items) -1:
                        self.state += 1'''
```

Код запуска игры

```
import pygame
from game import Game
from game import Camera
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

def main():
    # Initialize all imported pygame modules
    pygame.init()
    # Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    # Set the current window caption
    pygame.display.set_caption("PACMAN")
    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Create a game object
    game = Game()
    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        # --- Process events (keystrokes, mouse clicks, etc)
        done = game.process_events()
        # --- Game logic should go here
        game.run_logic()
        # --- Draw the current frame
        game.display_frame(screen)
        # --- Limit to 30 frames per second
        clock.tick(30)
        #tkMessageBox.showinfo("GAME OVER!","Final Score = "+(str)(GAME.score))
    # Close the window and quit.
    # If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit if running from IDLE.
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Можете подсказать как зафиксировать камеру на персонаже, пересмотрел кучу моментов но так зафиксировать не получилось

Comment: Вижу класс Camera, вижу его методы, а где сам объект self.camera =?

Comment: А что добавить в объект self.camera?

Comment: camera = Camera(), создание объекта из класса где-то должно быть, как game  = Game().

Comment: А что указать в камера , чтобы он понимал что такое x и y и куда перемещаться ?

Comment: Посмотри основы работы с камерой <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q666r0E9gTU&t=6s>